# angular 8 project with WordPress SEO friendly URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, routes, angular8

Im using angular 8 and there is one wordpress blog folder, it is working fine when url is not seo friendly but not with seo friendly as i have wild card redirect route inside angular app `** redirect to Errorpage`
Can you pls help

htaccess in angular app

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess of wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

https://machinesrentals.com is angular app to wordpress app

https://machinesrentals.com/blog/standart-post/  (not working)

https://machinesrentals.com/blog/ (working)
this is working fine but not internal pages of blog

Comment: Could you please share your htaccess rule file in your question? Also please do mention clearly from which URL TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect, that will make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: my question is updated with htaccess

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ??

Comment: Hi @Shafqat Jan, sorry I didn't understand you are typing only question marks to me? could you please elaborate on this one.

Comment: i added details regarding htaccess as you mentioned, can you pls help me out

Comment: I really didn't understand the question, else I would have replied to be honest. Could you please post/give samples or URLs which you want to rewrite/redirect I can try to help if I understand them brother :)

Comment: https://machinesrentals.com is angular app to wordpress app

https://machinesrentals.com/blog/standart-post/ (not working)

https://machinesrentals.com/blog/ (working) this is working fine but not internal pages of blog

they are already in question